# WebStorm: "move failed" when trying to move directory in project tree

Tags: webstorm

After pushing F6 and choosing destination folder I only get this message and no other clues. What could be the reason of this?

[image: Error message]

Comment: I've never seen this error and i move directories a lot. Webstorm needs to add more information to this error message (maybe a stack even)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where to get any additional information

Comment: I would go to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ and add it as a bug. Tell them also to put a more decent error message.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Node.js process was locking folders from being deleted. It's on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the error in Webstorm 2023.3.2 while working in a Vue TypeScript project. I closed all files and restarted the Vue TypeScript service in the statusbar on the bottom right and then it worked.